# bean validation working but empty message on Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, bean-validation

I'm trying to get Kotlin working with bean validation on spring-webflux project.
Requests seems to be validated properly, but message of a response body is empty, so it's difficult to know the cause of error.

Hot to get a default validation message from responses?

Controller:

```
class SomeController {
    @PostMapping("/foo")
    fun foo(@Valid @RequestBody body: FooRequest): Mono<FooRequest> {
        return Mono.just(body)
    }
}
```

Request:

```
data class FooRequest(
    @field:Min(0)
    val bar: Int
)
```

The response of calling that api with the request `"{\"bar\":-1}"` is

```
{
  "timestamp": "2021-03-23T02:18:49.368+00:00",
  "path": "/api/v1/foo",
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "",
  "requestId": "d1739c79-6"
}
```

Comment: I'm curious f you put a custom message in the annotation does it come thru? If it does it proves the annotation is the issue, otherwise something else.

Comment: just ran into the same isuue.

Comment: check you logs you have proper message in logs

Comment: @DCTID Even though I set a custom message, the response doesn't show that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after reading this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation

I ended up adding an exception handler like this:

```
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public ResponseEntity<Map<String,String>> handleMethodArgumentNotValidException(MethodArgumentNotValidException exception) {
    Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
    exception.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().forEach((error) -> {
        String fieldName = ((FieldError) error).getField();
        String errorMessage = error.getDefaultMessage();
        errors.put(fieldName, errorMessage);
    });
    return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
            .body(errors);
}
```